# Есть ли у твердого знака прописная буква?

Tags: прописная-строчная, алфавит

Есть ли у мягкого знака прописная буква?

Comment: Так Вы про твёрдый или мягкий знак? Хотя глобальной-то разницы нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если доверять словарям ([Ь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%8C*&all=x&lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x), [Ъ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%AA*)), то слова, начинающиеся на Ь и Ъ, в русском языке отсутствуют. Но сами символы, естественно, существуют. Например, для набора слов верхним регистром.

Answer (score 3):

Прописной может быть любая буква русского алфавита, в том числе и твёрдый знак.
Самые известные примеры:
[Паровозы серии Ъ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AA_(%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7))
[ПРОВАЛЪ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKholhytulU)
«Коммерса́нтъ-Daily» (до 1992 года просто «Коммерсантъ»; сокр. **«Ъ»**) — российская ежедневная общественно-политическая газета.

Другое дело — с твёрдого (или мягкого) знака слова не начинаются, поэтому прописная буква существует, если так можно сказать, "в связке" с каким-либо обозначением или словом.

28 **Ъ ъ** (твёрдый знак)
[Русский алфавит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82)
[Современный русский алфавит](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/630-14_grafika_bukvy_alfavit.html)